# No module named 'seaborn' even though its installed - windows (jupyter)

Tags: pip, anaconda, seaborn

I get this error on Jupyter

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'

but when I install it on the anaconda prompt I get this -

[image]

please help me :)

Comment: please check ur python version

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm which pip and which python version is used

```
python --version
python -m pip install seaborn
```

> pip3 may be pointing to an old or different python installation.

Comment: hey i got it solved finally! it was something wrong with my envs created. it wasnt pointing at the enviroment i was using.